# Golang to elastic- build dynamic query

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I'm new to Goleng and Elastic.
I have a static query that I took out of the Kibana, now I want to use this query to build a dynamic query code according to the parameters that the customer will send

how i add or remove "event_state.status" according  to user parameters.
how i convert this json to `map[string]interface {}`.
The client package i was use its https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch

this is the json query :

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "match_phrase": {
                        "webhook_id": "12345"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "minimum_should_match": 1
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "should": [
                          {
                            "match": {
                              "event_state.status": "rejected"
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match": 1
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "should": [
                          {
                            "match": {
                              "event_state.status": "succeeded"
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match": 1
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "should": [
                          {
                            "match": {
                              "event_state.status": "expired"
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match": 1
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "should": [
                          {
                            "match": {
                              "event_state.status": "inactive"
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match": 1
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "minimum_should_match": 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "created_at": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "2022-02-16T03:19:50.267Z",
              "lte": "2022-02-17T03:19:50.267Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "uuid.keyword",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "order by attempt_count",
      "size": 1,
      "sort": [
        {
          "event_state.attempt_count": "desc"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the query string in a raw string constant, the parts that you need to replace can be fitted with formatting directives such a %s, %d, %v.

Pass the raw string constant to fmt.Sprintf along with the variables in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at using the text/template module which is part of the go std library. https://pkg.go.dev/text/template

```
//The information you want to pass to your template
type Inventory struct {
    Material string
    Count    uint
}

var outputBuff bytes.Buffer

// define your template here 
queryTemplate := "{{.Count}} items are made of {{.Material}}"

queryParameters := Inventory{"wool", 17}

tmpl, err := template.New("test").Parse(queryTemplate)

if err != nil { panic(err) }

err = tmpl.Execute(&outputBuff, queryParameters)

if err != nil { panic(err) }

authoredQuery := outputBuff.String()
```